# System.Drawing Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, listview, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

```
 ImageList listImages = new ImageList();
 String[] imageFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\icones");
 foreach (var file in imageFiles) {
            //ajouter images a la listeImages
            listImages.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file));
}
```

I want to add image icons to my listview but I can't find a methode System.Drawing.Image.(***FromFile***) I found just this  Image.(**FromHbitamp**)
??? someone can help me ? i use cf 3.5

Comment: Pretty import to learn about the CF restrictions, this is well documented.  Use the Bitmap(string) constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer on [this forum](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/image-fromfile-compact-framework-help-37126032.html), for an icon you can first make a `FileStream` from your file path and then create an `Icon` from that using the appropriate `Icon` constructor.  For an ordinary `Bitmap` image, there's a `Bitmap` constructor that takes a path.

Comment: thanks for your answer .how can i do that ? give me an example please